# Окончание прилагательного

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Добрый день, "назначить временно исполняющей обязанности начальника" могу написать окончание "исполняющей" если заместитель начальника женщина???

Answer (score 2):

В официальном документе - не стоит. Трудовой кодекс не предусматривает гендерных вариантов для подобных должностей и ситуаций. 
А в разговоре, пожалуй, именно "женский" вариант предпочтителен.

Answer (score 0):

Можете, так как исполнять обязанности будет женщина.